# Is Hashem only God of the Jews?

Tags: theology

According to Exodus 20:2-3

> "I am the Lord, ***your God***, Who took you out of the land of Egypt, out of the house of bondage. You shall not have the gods of others in My presence.

There are various other instances where "your God" is said in reference to the Jewish nation.

**Are there any sources that show Hashem being called the God of any other nation or people?**

Comment: the word "your" does not have to mean yours exclusively. "your country", "your city", "your parents", etc. these are things that are yours but also may be shared by someone else

Comment: reason for downvotes?

Comment: Unfortunately, people don't always explain why they downvote.

Comment: There was also a mixed multitude of people there in Exodus 20:2-3 that God also redeemed from slavery. So I don't think this verse is referring only to the Jewish people, but rather everyone at Sinai whether Jewish or from another country/ethnicity.

Comment: God tells Pharaoh early on in Exodus -- "Israel is my firstborn." That implies there are other nations too to which God relates, but Israel is more special. Sforno comments -- they were the first to recognize God, but not the only ones nor the last.

Comment: @Bpotential This simply means that God identifies as the God of Israel. With Israel, it is personal, He gave Himself over like a husband to a wife, a sense of belonging, a romantic statement. But of course, there is only one God so you can't say the nations have _another_ god chas veshalom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[Jeremiah 32:27](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1132.htm#27)**

> 'Behold, I am the LORD, the God of all flesh; is there any thing too hard for Me?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is such a passage:

> **Hosea 2:23** ...I will have compassion on her on whom **compassion was not had,** and I will say to a people that was **not my people:** Thou **art my people,** and they: **Thou art my God.**

Israel cannot be "her on whom compassion was not had," since God called Abraham from idolatry to be sons of the living God and showered them with mercy above any nation; and from the rest of Scripture we know who "My People" refers to, namely, "Israel:"

> **2 Samuel 7:10** And I will appoint a place for **my people Israel,** and will plant them, and they shall dwell therein, and shall not be disturbed any more, neither shall the children of iniquity afflict them any more, as they did before.

So we see that God explicitly says that another people shall Israel shall be called His people, and that, therefore, they will say of Him, "Thou art my God."

But this isn't so shocking or sandalous, since converts to Judaism from other nations were existent, very much so, and therefore considered as much a part of Israel as anyone else: there was a very real conception of non-Jews by birth being capable of becoming Jews by circumcision, that is, of converts to the Jewish faith.

> **Judith 14:6** Then Achior seeing the power that the God of Israel had wrought, leaving the religion of the gentiles, he believed God, **and circumcised the flesh of his foreskin,** and **was joined to the people of Israel,** with all the succession of his kindred until this present day.

And of course there was the belief among the Maccabees that uncircumcised state of even uncircumcised *Jewish* children was 'heathenish,' and needed corrected as part of the crusade for restoring the tradition and orthodoxy to the Hellenized Jews:

> **1 Maccabees 2:46** And they **circumcised all the children whom they found in the confines of Israel that were uncircumcised:** and they did valiantly.

Moreover, God selected the Israelite people to be a light to the Gentiles, that is, the leaders and showers of the way, not the sole beneficiaries of the way:

> **Isaiah 49:6** And he said: It is a small thing that thou shouldst be my servant to raise up the tribes of Jacob, and to convert the dregs of Israel. Behold, I have given thee to be **the light of the Gentiles,** that thou mayst **be my salvation even to the farthest part of the earth.**

God chose Israel, but His sights were to all mankind, with Israel at the helm, showing the way, exemplifying the grace God grants to sinners, and showing the excellence of keeping His law, and the fruits thereof. The salvation and mercy He had on Israel was intended for all men, but He needed to form a people who were fully His first, in order to show that this is possible, admirable, and that in the very act of choosing a people among infinitudes of people, that it was all by the mercy of God: since He didn't choose Israel for its greatness: this is how the mercifulness of God is shown in choosing a special people to be a light to the Gentiles.

Comment: The New Testament is not an elephant in the room here. It's not even in the room at all. This is a Jewish site; by and large we don't care what is written in that work. Be careful, SolaGratia.

Comment: Why are you using the term "pre-Christian" when describing Jewish belief throughout history? Also, we don't really care what the NT says. This is a Jewish site.

Comment: @DoubleAA I invoked the New Testament as being relevant to the question on a purely historical/cultural level; I *did not* invoke it as an authority.  It's an "elephant in the room" absolutely in the sense that it has to do with the *biggest Jewish-born religion,* the longest-lasting/persistent/known, and the one which is *infamous* for *the very question being asked by OP.* No quoting Paul as an authority on Judaism. No quoting Maccabees or Judith as an authority, for that matter. Only Hosea. I also don't appreciate vague threats ("be careful").

Comment: I have no problem being explicit. The explicit threat is if you turn out to be a currently closeted missionary (which we've had here before) you will be unceremoniously banned. I hope that isn't the case but you must understand why we are very wary of people showing up and subtly and unnecessarily quoting Paul.

Comment: The biggest Jewish-born religion is not the subject of this site. It can be a very famous other religion and still not be relevant. Please remove discussion of it from the post.

Comment: The offending sentence has been removed. And any mention of Paul, Jesus, or the New Testament.

Comment: "a currently closeted missionary (which we've had here before) you will be unceremoniously banned" I'm a Christian, but I'm absolutely not a missionary trying to convert anyone here only trying to answer and help, but I appreciate the felt need to guard what you have here against such. It was my impression anyone can answer any question on this site, and I answered from purely Jewish sources (yes, even the heretical New Testament is Jewish, but if you don't want that on your corner of SE, then that's respectable) in light of that.

Comment: @Sola Just to fill you in on MY history, we had a missionary masquerading as a rabbi on this site. We truly welcome those who use the site correctly and honestly. (there's a list of rules somewhere).

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel "we had a missionary masquerading as a rabbi on this site" I understand; and that's shameful. However, you don't need to have that worry or suspicion with me — I'm happily Christian and will remain so until I breathe my last. You don't have to worry about me being a pretend Rabbi lol. Nor that I'm here to convert anyone to any religion, including Christianity. Just here to offer what I think could be helpful answers. Sometimes they aren't, sometimes they are. God bless.

Comment: Welcome ABOARD!! :)

Comment: @SolaGratia I see no problem quoting sources from your religion if it speaks the truth. People seem to forget that Rambam said to listen to the truth no matter the source (including the Christian new testament!) Since most Jews are atheists, we should hardly be focused on Christian missionaries pretending to be rabbis. Atheism is a bigger threat to Jews and Christians are actually our best friend to the modern state of Israel. I wonder if you said you were a secular Jew would they say "be careful"?

Comment: @TurkHill laws of kings and wars 11:6

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Elsewhere he writes that G-d used Christianity and Islam as a tool to teach the gentiles familiar Jewish concepts so that they may accept the Jewish messiah. In any case, I agree with R Asher, better a Christian than an atheist! At least a Christian (albeit wrong theology) is religious, has morals, and believes in the Bible. Also, 90% of Jews are secular. They think they are G-d. Isn't that more idolatrous!? Let's be honest here. How many Jews you know who are Christian? Meanwhile, Jews are plagued with atheism. Atheism is a bigger threat to Judaism than Christianity. That's a fact.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Also, see what he writes in the next verse: "Nonetheless, the Thoughts of the Creator of the World are beyond any man’s understanding. For our ways are not His Ways, and our thoughts are not His Thoughts. And all the doings of Jesus the Nazarene and that of that Ishmaelite who came after him are nothing but to pave the way for the King Messiah and prepare the entire world to worship G-d."

Comment: If they think they are god they aren't far off for the alternative, then--- ;) I'm just joshin with you, thanks, all the best

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel What is "the alternative?"

Comment: Your edits drastically improved your post. Not just because we get weirded out by Christiany stuff, but because your point is better made by focusing on Judaism rather than Christianity. The point of this site is to offer answers through the lens of Judaism, not to discuss "pre Christianity." Your answers should start from Judaism and move forward, not start at Christianity and move backwards.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel The rules used to be in the tour section. Has it been moved?

Answer (score 3):

The haftarah for P' Ki Tisa (excerpted from I Kings 18) concludes (Nusach Ashkenaz) with the the verse

> וַיַּרְא֙ כָּל־הָעָ֔ם וַֽיִּפְּל֖וּ עַל־פְּנֵיהֶ֑ם וַיֹּ֣אמְר֔וּ ה֙ ה֣וּא הָאֱלֹהִ֔ים ה֖ ה֥וּא הָאֱלֹהִֽים׃
>
> And the people saw and fell on their faces and said: Hashem, He is G-d, Hashem, He is G-d.

They don't say ה׳ הוא ﭏקינו (Hashem, he is our G-d) and they only come to the realisation after turning aside to follow false deities (Baal being the one in question in this episode).

Throughout the prophets, we find references to G-d's universality, perhaps most famously in Zechariah (14:9)

> וְהָיָ֧ה ה֛ לְמֶ֖לֶךְ עַל־כׇּל־הָאָ֑רֶץ בַּיּ֣וֹם הַה֗וּא יִהְיֶ֧ה ה֛ אֶחָ֖ד וּשְׁמ֥וֹ אֶחָֽד׃
>
> And Hashem shall be King over all the earth; In that day Hashem shall be One, and His name one.

Answer (score 3):

In Reb Avigdor Miller On Tefilla (great book) one of the kavaonos he says for 'elokainu' in shema is  that right now he is our G-d, but in the future he will be recognized as everyone's G-d. So while Hashem is the G-d of the whole world and the creator of the whole world, it isn't widely recognized.

Comment: Great observation! This also seems the idea of Rashi in his commentary on Devarim 6:4, "The Lord who is now our G-d and not the G-d of the other peoples of the world, He will at some future time be the One (sole) ה׳,"

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: @KovyJacob If G-d is for everyone, is everybody chosen in the future?

Comment: @TurkHill what does that mean?

Comment: @KovyJacob I think Rashi is stating the idea that while G-d is only the G-d of the Jews now, He will be G-d of all people someday. Personally, I hold that G-d is the G-d of the world (ie everyone).

Comment: @TurkHill Right, he just isn't recognized as such by non-Jews.

Answer (score 1):

[**Amos 9:7**](https://www.sefaria.org/Amos.9.7?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi)

> הֲל֣וֹא כִבְנֵי֩ כֻשִׁיִּ֨ים אַתֶּ֥ם לִ֛י בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל נְאֻם־יְהֹוָ֑ה הֲל֣וֹא אֶת־יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל הֶעֱלֵ֙יתִי֙ מֵאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם וּפְלִשְׁתִּיִּ֥ים מִכַּפְתּ֖וֹר וַאֲרָ֥ם מִקִּֽיר׃
>
> To Me, O Israelites, you are
> just like the Cushites
> —declares the Lord.
> True, I brought Israel up
> from the land of Egypt,
> but also the Philistines from Caphtor
> and the Arameans from Kir.

Comment: This suggests that someday other nations shall be chosen, too.

Comment: @TurkHill No it does not. It's simply saying God had a hand in the history of those people like he did with Israel

Comment: @ezra Why didn't these people record what G-d did for them like we did?

Comment: Every culture tells its own history, filtered through its own cultural preconceptions. I would be more surprised if the Philistines didn't attribute their own history to Dagon or another of their idols.

Comment: @TurkHill They did, but this was attributed to their gods instead. These events in the passuk actually happened in history, the Plishtim coming from Kaftor and Arami from Kir.

Comment: @ezra I agree with you.

Comment: @Mike Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. G-d is not just the G-d of the Jews but the G-d of all people. Moses said:

"If this G-d is G-d, he would live on every mountain. In every valley. He would not be only the G-d of Israel alone but of all men. It is said he created all men in his image. He would dwell in every heart. In every mind. In every soul."

Comment: Where did Moses say that?

Comment: Can't wait to read that 6th book of the Torah lol.